# What happens when I remove an Xbox Live friend?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I've got some "friends" on my Xbox Live friends list who aren't really that - they're people I rarely play with and who are more "friends of friends."  Unfortunately, the friends list pings me every time they're online or doing something (ie, they start playing the game I'm playing) which is kind of inconvenient.

I'm considering removing them, but I don't want to "cause a scene" and offend them (or my other friends) by removing them.

What happens when I remove an Xbox Live friend?  Do they get a notification?  Does anything change from their perspective?

Comment: <Gets all offended> FINE! I DIDNT WANT TO BE YOUR FRIEND EITHER!  ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They get no notification, you will however get removed from their friend list as well.